# using error.appendTo method in error placement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1 and  trying to show the error in particular div and I successfully did but the problem is error is appended to the previous error . This what I've done

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
               error.appendTo($("#error"));
              }
```

Please suggest me to avoid this scenario. Thanks in  advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the contents of your `<div>` to be replaced by the current error element.

The `error` argument to your function refers to a regular jQuery element, a `<label>` by default. This being true, you can just use any DOM manipulation you want to make sure your error label is the only thing in the error `div`. For example:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $("#error").empty().append(error);
}
```

or, if anything else is present in your `div#error` that you want to keep there (assuming your `errorClass` is still `error`):

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo($('#error')).siblings('.error').remove();
}
```